# Facebook FQL stream query only returning 4 items

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-fql, photos

I am trying to retrieve all Photos from a user's stream.

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, created_time 
FROM stream 
WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() 
AND type='newsfeed') 
AND type = 247 
AND is_hidden = 0 
ORDER BY created_time DESC
```

This only returns 4 results, and they are very recent posts. If I try to include a 'created_time < 1360993620' clause, it returns zero results. Is there any reason why this query does not go very far into the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an easier way to do what I'm trying to do is to use the Graph API to pull a user's home feed and then filter it for only the photo posts:

```
GET /me/home?filter=app_2305272732
```